# How would I create the database for this scenario in Prolog?

Tags: database, prolog

The first image is an image of a symantic net diagram and is an image of a scenario from my college assignment I was wondering if anyone was able to help me I am trying to work out how to fix the database in the Prolog program for the scenario and i am having trouble please help Thanks in advance!

This is the diagram of the scenario

[image: Diagram]

This is what I have tried so far in terms of the database

[image: Database]

Comment: what image? what scenario? BTW SO is NOT a free coding service. Show what you have tried.

Comment: You should read [how this website works](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Apologies for the inconvenience I have included the images to the question

Comment: All you need to do to properly show an image is click the image button when you are editing and enter the prompted information.

Comment: Prolog doesn't understand database relationships *per se*, but it does allow you to define terms completely to your liking to mean what you want. So you can define, for example, `isa(herduvet, duvet).` Prolog doesn't know what `isa` means, but you and the rest of your program do. :)

Answer (score 1):

It of course all depends on how you structure a database, but *relational databases* store (no joke) *relations*, so for your small example, one would define five predicates:

- `isa/2`;
- `owns/2`;
- `ako/2`;
- `made_of/2`; and
- `colour/2`.

Your database then would look like:

```
isa('Pat',person).
isa(herduvet,duvet).

ako(cover,duvet).
ako(duvet,bedding).

owns('Pat',herduvet).

made_of(ducksfeathers,herduvet).

colour(ducksfeathers,white).
```